# SQL Server : Group by Replace NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table like this :

```
 | id | column_a | column_b |
 |  1 |  NULL    | 111      |
 |  1 |  222     | NULL     |
 |  2 |  NULL    | 333      |
 |  2 |  444     | NULL     |
```

i want to group it like this

```
 | id | column_a | column_b |
 |  1 |  222     | 111      |
 |  2 |  444     | 333      |
```

Column_a and column_b is varchar. and pattern NULL value is consistent.
How can i do that?

Comment: What will happen if there is an additional row with `1,100,200` ?

Comment: Warning: The above example is not the real problem, q.v. my deleted answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The aggregate function SUM don't handle NULL in the same way as ordinary functions and operators. Instead of returning NULL as soon as a NULL operand is encountered, it only take non-NULL fields into consideration while computing the outcome.

So, you can resolve it this way..

```
select id, sum(column_a) as column_a, 
sum(column_b) as column_b 
from tbl1
group by id;
```

[**Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/651e3/1)

Answer (score 0):

try this one as well...

> ```
> select id, sum(nvl(column_a,0)) as column_a, 
> sum(nvl(column_b,0)) as column_b 
> from tbl1
> group by id;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not to add app numeric values..

maybe you mean something like this..

```
select ISNULL(ta.id,tb.id) id, ta.a,tb.b
from 
(select * from t where a is not null) ta
full join
(select * from t where b is not null) tb
on ta.id = tb.id
```

you should explain better the nature of the problem

as @sagi said, what kind of values will receive this table? only two records for each id? one with 1st column null and second column not null and vice versa?

or there are other scenarios?